# The existence of OWFs vs $\mathbf{EXP} \neq \mathbf{BPP}$

Tags: one-way-function, hardness-assumptions

In CRYPTO 2021, Liu and Pass published a paper with title ["On the Possibility of Basing Cryptography on   $\mathbf{EXP} \neq \mathbf{BPP}$](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-84242-0_2).

One of the main results of this work can be interpreted as an indication that the existence of OWFs is equivalent to $\mathbf{EXP} \neq \mathbf{BPP}$.
$\mathbf{EXP} \neq \mathbf{BPP}$ is a weak assumpation, what is the relation between this assumpation and the average-case hardness?
Any introduction and comment about this work is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathsf{EXP}\neq \mathsf{BPP}$ is the typical assumption used in the derandomization literature. Words to search are "Nisan-Widgerson" and "Impagliazzo-Widgerson". For example, the abstract of [Impagliazzo-Widgerson](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Eavi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IW98/proc.pdf) reads:

> We prove that if $\mathsf{BPP}\neq \mathsf{EXP}$, then every problem in $\mathsf{BPP}$ can be solved deterministically in subexponential time on almost every input (on every samplable ensemble for infinitely many
> input sizes). This is the first derandomization result for $\mathsf{BPP}$ based on uniform, non-cryptographic hardness assumptions. It implies the following gap in the average-instance complexities of problems in $\mathsf{BPP}$ : either these complexities are always sub-exponential or they contain arbitrarily large exponential functions.

In general, when looking into a new area PhD thesis can be mildly easier to read than papers, so if you're interested more [Marco Carmosino's thesis](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/8tb0q56g) may be useful.